# Party up with friends on other platforms?

Tags: fall-guys-ultimate-knockout

Now that Fall Guys is free to play and cross platform, I finally had the chance to test it out

When I open the party menu, I can invite people from my Epic Games friends list (PC player here) and I think, to some extent with people playing from Steam who linked their steam account with their Epic Games account

However, I have some friends who are likely to play on the Nintendo Switch

Is there a way for me/them to invite ourselves to a single party?

Comment: so, I just found out that you can login into your epic games account by using a steam, PSN, XBL, Nintendo, apple, google, or fb account
maybe by linking them to said epic account
so, what can I do with this question now that I found out the answer?

Comment: Never had to do it but I would guess everything goes through the epic account. So you don't invite the Nintendo account, you invite the Epic account.

Comment: You can answer your own question with the information you found, since somebody else may have the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After going around the Fall Guys discord server, and trying to log in to the Epic Games Store via an incognito browser, and seeing the different ways of logging in (Epic Games account, Steam account, Google account, Facebook account, XBox Live account, Playstation Network account, Nintendo account, Apple account), it is now clear that I will need my friends to link their Nintendo account to an Epic Games account for me to see when they're online and playing the game

I do believe this is how you get your friends playing on other platforms to play with you